# Why after --disable-web-security and deleting x-frame-options header this error still showing?

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, electron, cross-domain, code-injection

I'm creating a webapp in electron, a web-crawler with a neural network, which needs all webSecurities to be disabled

i tried modifying the headers (`X-Frame-Origin`,`access-control-allow-origin`
etc..) , using flags like `chrome --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=""` etc... nothing seems to remove the error above

The iframe is showing the ORIGIN restricted websites after i modified the xframe header, but when i try to access its document, the error above pops

i tried running it in chrome and firefox, and the same behaviour is encoutered

been googling for 4 hours now and i can't seem to find an appropriate answer. if you think this is a duplicated please include a link, it would help a lot

[image: error in chrome devtool]

Comment: can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found the solution ,the disable site isolation trial should be toggled on :

> app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-site-isolation-trials')

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found that is not deprecated (so far, to this date) is the bellow, old aproaches like `webPreferences: { webSecurity: false }` wont work anymore as webSecurity no longer controls CORS.

```
mainWindow.webContents.session.webRequest.onHeadersReceived({ urls: [ "*://*/*" ] },
(d, c)=>{
    if(d.responseHeaders['X-Frame-Options']){
        delete d.responseHeaders['X-Frame-Options'];
    } else if(d.responseHeaders['x-frame-options']) {
        delete d.responseHeaders['x-frame-options'];
    }
    c({cancel: false, responseHeaders: d.responseHeaders});
}
```

);